# JSP compilation error For IBM JDK 1.5 Servlet version 2.5

Tags: java, jsp, ibm-jdk

I'm using IBM JDK and Eclipse Hellos. When I'm devloping simple web project, I'm getting error in compilation of jsp page. If I change my JDK to normal Sun JDK, then every thing's working fine. But I have to use IBM jdk as production environment; I have to use web sphere.

The error I'm getting is this:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated Java file 

The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
```

Can anyone tell me what I have to do?

Comment: Not without seeing the error, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory.html#getJspApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29) is undefined for the type `JspFactory` - this means that `JspFactory` on the classpath does not have the desired method. The method is available since version 2.1 of the servlet api, so make sure you don't have any servlet-api, jsp-api or el-api in `WEB-INF/lib`, and that your WebSphere supports Servlet 2.1.

Comment: i'm developing a very simple web project in Eclipse. which content a single jsp page named as index.jsp with html code only. In web-inf/lib folder i don't have any jar file. I have not set any class path in my system. as i'm developing the apps with Eclipse Helleos and IBM jdk 1.5